# how to connect vmware network for data with port-channel links?

Tags: vmware

I have new DellEMC server having 4 physical ports and installed ESXI 6.0 successfully
2 ports - management network
2 ports - data network

when i connect 2 ports from physical switch by making port-channel / lacp to vmware machine
there is shown following error:

> Port-channel14 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
> Hardware is EtherChannel, address is 0000.0000.0000 (bia 0000.0000.0000)
> Description: CONN_MBL_UAT_VM_NEW   MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec,
> DLY 100 usec,
> reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255   Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set   Keepalive set (10 sec)   Auto-duplex,
> Auto-speed, link type is auto, media type is   input flow-control is
> on, output flow-control is unsupported   ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout
> 04:00:00   Last input never, output never, output hang never   Last
> clearing of "show interface" counters never

...

please help me to solve the issue and also i have query "may i able to achieve lacp without vsphere only from vmware"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to configure LACP you need a switch that support this feature with protocol 802.3ad with route ip hash enable. Then the first step is configure lacp on vmware and finally enable Lacp on switch. I attach some docs with examples.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001938

Any question let me know.

Comment: I have also configured in physical cisco switch but still problem not resolved. please help me , great thanks for your support

Comment: Hello sorry for late response, can you tell me your cisco switch model? And please, share an image with your distributed switch configuration. With this information we can see Whats wrong.